# Unable to find provider assembly with name Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlLite

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-core, .net-core

Project is .NetCore 2.2
Nuget Packages:
* Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design (2.2.0)
* Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite (2.2.0)
* Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools (2.2.0)

Running Command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=blogging.db;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite -OutputDir Models
```

Produces Error:

```
Unable to find provider assembly with name Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlLite. Ensure the specified name is correct and is referenced by the project.
```

Answer (score 13):

I was getting this error:

```
Unable to find provider assembly with name Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer. Ensure the specified name is correct and is referenced by the project.
```

I fixed it by adding this to the <ItemGroup> element in the project file.

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.5" />
```

Answer (score 13):

The fix as mentioned was to add the SQL framework.  You can add it very quickly via the package manager console using:

Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer

Comment: Fixed it for me, make sure you select the project in the package manager console window for where you want to scaffold to.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this error by installing EntityFrameworkCore through nuget package manager. Also the project the EntityFrameworkCore packages installed, should be referred in the project you try to create models.